# Is OAuth2 with Google Gadgets on Google Sites supported?

Tags: google-oauth, google-sites, opensocial

My various Google Gadgets embedded on Google Sites broke yesterday with the deprecation of OAuth1 by Google.  I am unable to find a working example of an oauth2 gadget that works on Google Sites.

Could anybody kindly confirm that this is indeed supposed to work and do you have an example? :)

My fear is that the note on this page: https://developers.google.com/gadgets/docs/basic

> Note: Writing OAuth gadgets is no longer supported.

spells bad news for me!

Comment: Found this unanswered thread from 2012 https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-apps-gadgets-api/5z3TvNcZxKg

Comment: Have you been able to find the workaround?

Comment: @CodeBusta I abandoned Gadgets and started using https://script.google.com (Google Apps Script)

Comment: Before I switch to Google Apps Script, I want to confirm whether the following is possible. The way I used gadgets - I have a Business App for Business account. My users opened their email in their gmail box. And below the email content they were able to sign in and do this and that in my other application using its API requests. Is this process can be replicated in Google Apps Script?